# Открыть ссылку в python

Tags: python, url, request, urllib

Требуется открыть сайт "[https://где-ударение.рф](https://%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%D1%80%D1%84)" и далее его страницы (например, 
"[https://где-ударение.рф/в-слове-ногтя/](https://%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%82%D1%8F/)"). Зеркало главной страницы через URL - https://xn----8sbhebeda0a3c5a7a.xn--p1ai/". Когда пытаюсь это сделать, выдает следующую ошибку (см. фото). Как можно это исправить? Пробовал кодировать через urllib.quote, и через 'url'.encode('utf-8') - никак не работает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CertificateError: hostname 'где-ударение.рф' doesn't match either of 'www.xn----8sbhebeda0a3c5a7a.xn--p1ai', 'xn----8sbhebeda0a3c5a7a.xn--p1ai'

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста ([edit])

Comment: попробуйте использовать модуль `requests` - все отлично работает: `import requests; html = requests.get("https://где-ударение.рф/в-слове-ногтя/").text`

Comment: приведите код, чтобы можно было воспроизвести